# Catch block behavior

Tags: java

What is the behavior of catch block, if it is not at the end of the block.

```
private Boolean connect(String addr) {
.....
   try {

         connected = true;

   } catch (ExceptionType name) {
       //log // print stack trace etc, but no explicit return

   } catch (ExceptionType name) {

   }

   if (some_other_condn) {

     ..
   }
}
```

Do one need return inside catch block if I don't want to execute rest of the code in the block?

Comment: And why should you think that someone would answer when you have not even tried it out in a program ?

Comment: This question might decrease your rep enough for it to take longer to get your edit privileges. Please don't use us as servants.

Comment: I am not fluent in Java. Also thought people will take it lightly. Sorry for it sounded the way you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do need to return from the `catch` block if you don't want to execute rest of the code.

Or, better just put the rest of the code within the `try` block itself.

```
try {
    connected = true;
    if (some_other_condn) {    
        //...
    }
} catch (ExceptionType name) {
   //log // print stack trace etc, but no explicit return
} catch (ExceptionType name) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. If you don't want to execute rest of the code, you need to return (But you will be returned on exception case only, I hope you know about that). Success case your return statement won't execute.